# Invoke jquery method on a dynamically added DOM element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The `preview` variable contains HTML code like `<div id='abc'>...</div>`. I must invoke a jquery method for that DOM element, but the following code makes no changes. It seems that `$('#abc').someMethod();` code is not being invoked if the `abc` element is added dynamically to the document. How can I fix it?

```
 $("#pdf-dialog").dialog("option" , 'open' , function() { 
     @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(preview))
     {
         <text>
             $("#pdf-dialog").html("@preview");
         </text>
     }
 });
 ...
 @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(preview))
 {
     <text>
          $('#abc').someMethod();
     </text>
 }
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant javascript as it is emitted without the MVC code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the method is bound to the matching elements on document load. Since you add the elements to the document after that you need to bind your method again. Usually you do this in the same function that adds the elements to the DOM.